# Swift IPv6 support

Tags: ios, swift, networking, ipv6

I'm trying to submit my iOS app in Apple. But they have rejected my app because of problems with IPv6: they tried to connect to our server from IPv6 network, and it wasn't successfull.
We changed our server side: now our server is ready to use IPv6 (I tested it on ipv6test.com, and everything was good).
In my app I'm using **URLSession.shared.dataTask** to create request. And Apple got problem in such line of code:

```
var urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: myServerUrl);
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST";
..... //preparing POST data, setting timeout, etc.
urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies - true;
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
do {
    guard let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkError.connectionError;} //here they got a problem
....
}
catch {...}
```

I don't understand, why they cannot connect to our server. From our network (IPv4) everything is good.
And the main strange thing: I sent this app yesterday at 10:05. At 10:30 we've seen one request from the Apple's network, and it was successfull (200 status). It looks very strange, because they wrote, that they cannot even authorize in this app...
Please, can somebody help with this situation? I don't understand, where is a problem, and what should I do.

Comment: do you have a physical device with a sim card?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have physical device without SIM. And I tested my app in emulator. But before submission, I installed my app in 2 real devices with SIM cards, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Chances are that the problem is unrelated to IPv6 and Apple (for some reason) just could not authorize in your app. Why do you think that the problem is related to this specific part in your code?

Comment: Because I've added "breakpoints" - in catch block I show the step in my program where problem has appeared. I set timeout (60 seconds) to this request. Apple says, that app tries to connect during 1 minute, and after that shows this error. So, it is timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You should test issues like this by setting up a DNS64/NAT64 network using a Mac. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16)

Chances are that's what their QA are doing.

Comment: I don't unserstand where is a problem: I didn't use any third-party libraries for networking, and I used only URLSession, as they recommend. Our server is ready to process requests from IPv6 network. Where is the problem?

Comment: No idea where the problem is, but the best first step is being able to repro the issue yourself, so I'd suggest you setup the Mac according to Apple's recommendations. Even if it doesn't let you repro the problem, then at least you can tell Apple what you tried and ask them to give it another go. I assume you're using a proper URL and not an IP address literal?

Comment: Yes, in my app I'm using string URL (like `https://myaddress.com`). I have static constant in one of my classes. It looks like this: `static let serverUrl = "https://myaddress.com";`. And in other classes I concat parts, like `/login`